# ConfigMap for ASP.NET Core 6 application hosted in Azure App Service or Function App Container hosting

Tags: asp.net, kubernetes, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

AKS / Kubernetes allows configurable items to be part of [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) files, which can be mounted as a volume into a container.

When that is combined with ASP.NET Core's `Options` pattern, we can effectively externalize environment specific configurations into separate config file say `appsettings.dev.json`. A K8 or Helm deploy can install the image as a container in AKS, apply the `appsettings.dev.json` file as ConfigMap to bring in the envt specific configs.

That way, the release pipeline has precious little to do other than a `helm upgrade --install`.

App Services and function app container hosting allows the same image to be hosted on the app service / function app. The ability to apply the `appsettings.dev.json` as a ConfigMap appears to be missing.

The alternative is to read everything from `appsettings.dev.json` during the release and apply it as configuration overrides in the app service "configuration" section.

Can someone advise if there is a ConfigMap or similar feature available in app service to apply environment config as a file during release instead of a bunch of key value settings?